# Does WSO2 Micro Integrator Supports Kafka 2.3.1 Inbound Endpoint to read messages from Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

'I am working on a Kafka Integration, where I a publishing and reading messages from topic.
I am able to publish messages to topic but unable to read those messages using inbound endpoint.
When I checked WSO2 documentation, they are recommending Kafka kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1 which is very old.
Can't we use the latest version of Kafka with Micro Integrator? Can any one suggest please.'

Comment: I'm able to see `Kafka 2.12-0.11.0.0` in the documentation,which would work fine for later brokers. What are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Kafka Inbound endpoint from the WSO2 connector store, then you should be able to use the latest versions. Checkout this documentation https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-inbound-kafka/blob/release-1.0.7/docs/config.md

Also checkout this github issue thread https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2239

Comment: Hi Arunan, As per the link you provided WSO2 is recommended kafka version is  kafka_2.12-1.0.0 but we are using 2.3.1. I am using inbound endpoint from the wso2 connector store. But I am getting below error. Can you please suggested is wso2 inbound endpoint connector supports 2.3.1 version of kafka or not. Thanks.

Comment: Below is the error which I am getting    
 `kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v133`